# Cannot route to a url with a different protocol with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, window.open

I am trying to open an application client side and I have developed this entire application using only angularjs as a front end. It seems to be hijacking the routing and disallowing this.

In old javascript I used to be able to do

```
var wnd = window.open("dynamicsnav://arbitraryLinkDetails", "_blank");
wnd.close(); // this opens the protocol to start the application client 
             // side and closes the extra browser window
```

to open the Nav application client side and the details of what to open in place of arbitraryLinkDetails.

Now when I do this inside of my angular app it appends localhost to the url(really it is the base domain it attaches) like this

```
    "http://localhost/"dynamicsnav://arbitraryLinkDetails""
```

which does not work.

Things I have tried

1. appending "//" to the url to break out of the angularjs routing, this tacks on a %22 to the beginning and removed the : for the protocol like "%22dynamicsnav//arbitraryLinkDetails"
2. I have tried modifying the routing so

   ```
   var redirectFunction(){
       return theUrl; //this gets the full url of dynamicsnav://arbitraryLinkDetails
   }
   $routeProvider
      .when('/NavUrl', {redirectTo: redirectFunction})
   ```

   and that again appended base url to it.

This is a requirement for my current project and I simply cannot figure out a way to open this like I used to with angularjs.

I verified the url's I am testing with work in another application not using angular. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AngularJS $routeProvider service manage routes that deep link controllers with views, wich is not your case, why don't you try this :

```
var redirectFunction(){
    window.open("dynamicsnav://arbitraryLinkDetails", "_blank");
}
$routeProvider
   .when('/NavUrl', {redirectTo: redirectFunction})
```

Comment: Ok so this works great! The only annoying part is since it is changing the routing to "/NavUrl" it changes the controller and view that was loaded and the page now comes up blank. Is there any way to avoid that?